# url exclusion in SharePoint crawl rule not working

Tags: search, crawl-rules

I don't want "AllItems.aspx" to appear in sharepoint search results  from any level/ folder. So I created new crawl rule http://.*/forms/allitems.aspx and checked the regular expression check box. Gave Full crawl of content source.

But unfortunately "AllItems.aspx" still shows up in sharepoint search results. If anyone could point what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I think you look at the problem from the wrong view. You actually do want to include allitems.aspx to be crawled but none of the other views.  To make this work you need to make a crawl rule that includes allitems.aspx as order 1, and an exclusion rule that skips all other views - like this:

[image]

[image]

With this all af your documents are beeing crawled only once, which is a good thing. Exluding allitems.aspx could make documents not crawled - and if so, they can't be found in search.

But to overcome your problem, you need to exclude allitems.aspx in the result source - like this:

```
-filename:allitems.aspx
```

Now you have all documents crawled, but are not showing the allitems.aspx in your search result.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out, but with my knowledge of regular expressions.. shouldn't it be something like:

```
.+/forms/allitems.aspx$
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating regular expressions for crawl rules you need to include the protocol (http(s)://) So it must start with http:// (https://) then follow by your pattern. Else SharePoint will be kind and add it.

I think you are looking for something like this http://*/forms/allitems.aspx[?]*
In case there is a link pointing to allitems.aspx with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the order of your Crawl Rules. The exclusion should be before inclusion. The order is important in Crawl Rules.